# Ayuda con Ejercicio con Punteros (Muy Difícil) (Lenguaje C)

Tags: c, punteros, memoria

Me ayudan con este ejercicio? No entiendo nada. cómo muestro cómo se almacena en memoria? cómo muestro el numero en decimal y hexadecimal(no es lo mismo que pasar a binario y octal porque esto lleva letras)? y como hago que lo muestre Byte por Byte? Es un ejercicio muy exagerado para principiantes como yo   Empezamos informatica desde cero (no programé nunca) hace 2 meses y aunque no lo crean, ahora vamos con punteros

[image: s]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes una variable entera guardando un valor, lo puedes mostrar con `printf`, tanto en decimal como hexadecimal, como su dirección.

```
int variable;
printf("%d", variable);    // Código %d para decimales
printf("%x", variable);    // Código %x para hexadecimal
```

Para imprimir la dirección de memoria de una variable, usamos el código `%p` en `printf`, y le pasamos la dirección de la variable, que se obtiene con el operador `&`.

```
printf("%p", &variable);
```

Para imprimir la variable byte a byte, puedes utilizar una variable puntero a byte, iniciándola a la dirección de la variable. Como cada dirección apunta a un solo byte, puedes ir sumando de uno en uno para obtener cada byte. Pero ojo, porque un entero puede ser 4 bytes, o puede ser 8. En realidad, no tiene un ancho definido, solo un mínimo.

```
byte * parte1 = &variable;
byte * parte2 = parte1 + 1;
...
```

Quedaría hacer los castings apropiados e imprimir el valor en hexadecimal, pero ya tienes todo para solucionarlo.

También debes tener en cuenta, además del ancho de tu tipo de datos, según tu máquina, si tu máquina es big endian o little endian, porque los bytes del entero se pueden guardar del mas significativo al menos significativo, o al revés.